# chatter feed on salesforce1 page without standard stylesheet

Tags: visualforce, chatter, salesforce1-platform

I have a VF page which is marked for mobile devices and has,  docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
I want to show chatter feed on this page.
When I use  on the page it doesn't render correctly which I believe because starndarStyleSheets is set to false.
I want to keep it as false as I am using Mobile design templates.

Any idea whats is the quickest way to show a chatter feed with correct styling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of that you could achieve this without replicating all of the styling would be to include an iframe in your VF page that includes another VF page with standard styling and the chatter feed component.  I suspect you'll have some problems getting the size of the frame correct, and it will likely include scrollbars when the main page won't.

Comment: will try this, thx!